# Access data- Attribute from jqGrid Select List

Tags: javascript, java, free-jqgrid

I want to access the data- attribute from an option in a jqGrid select list.

My Servlet result(console - test code only):

```
<select><option data-htoObj='SDE' value='0'></option><option data-htoObj='SDE' value='1'>Items</option>
```

My js code(jqGrid):

beforeInitData function:

```
$("#hospitalqueue").setColProp('htypei', { editoptions: {     dataUrl: '/QMSWebApp/HospitalControllerServlet?lifecycle=typelist'},  defaultValue: 0});

$("#hospitalqueue").setColProp('htypei', { editoptions: {dataEvents: [{ type: 'change', fn: function(e) {hospitaltype(this);  }},]}});
```

hospitaltype function:

```
var htobj = obj.getAttribute("data-htoObj");
alert("1: " + htobj);
```

alert 1 returns null

Answer (score 0):

Your function should look like this:

```
function hospitaltype ( obj ) {
    var data_atr = $(obj.options[obj.selectedIndex]).attr('data-htoObj');
}
```

and call it with parameter this - i.e

```
hospitaltype(this);
```

Kind Regards

Comment: Thanks for the help. What my original intent is to have a JSON string defined as the data-htoObj. Example: data-htoObj='{"recseq":"2","description":"Dimensions"}'. How can I access each pair of values?